# Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Network Error + Require Cycle

Tags: typescript

A screenshot of the error in my terminal. It shows that Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle, but I don't know how to solve that and the Network error. I'm creating an app using typescript and a bit of javascript so if you know the answer, please let me know!

Right now, the error I'm trying to solve is:

Require cycle:
`components/FeedBlock/index.tsx -> screens/Profile.tsx -> components/FeedBlock/index.tsx`

Require cycles are allowed but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
at screens of `Profile.tsx`, `FeedBlock.tsx`, `Home.tsx` and `App.tsx`

[image: screenshot of the require cycle error in ios simulator (I'm using expo)]
[image: the screenshot of the error in my terminal]

Comment: We're going to need more context - can you copy-paste both the errors and the minimal amount of the components in question to trigger the warning when you build and we can help you out more.

Comment: Why does FeedBlock/index.tsx depend on (import?) screens/Profile.tsx and vice versa? Ideally one would depend on the other, one-way.